# In a Fish that is not a Fish

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, animals

> Righteous head of a snake that is a snake,
> Aback, held in a fish that is not a fish.
> Now, I'm beauty in disguise,
> Despite being, to most, nightmarish.

I am looking for two answers... One on the surface, and one in disguise, with a pun :)

Comment: That acrostic is interesting.

Comment: @RandalThor how is RAND interesting? intelligent and observant, you may say. but interesting?? *That's* interesting :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Righteous head of a snake that is a snake,

> **rat**tlesnake - is a snake, with rat at its head.

Aback, held in a fish that is not a fish.

> s**tar**fish - rat back inside an echinoderm.

Now, I'm beauty in disguise,

> art - rat disguised in an anagram.

Despite being, to most, nightmarish.

> rat - fear of rats and mice is musophobia.

Second connection

> Rand is an acrostic - credit to Rand al'Thor - with initials the same as these intelligent mammals.